Springboot merging properties while reading as Map
enter code hereIs there a way to only get the profile specific properties if reading them as Map<String, String>.
Springboot, reading "user" property as Map<String, String> using @ConfigurationProperties
Example:
application-local.yml
    user:
      key1: value1
      key2: value2
application-dev.yml
    user:
      key1: dev-value
      key3: value3

when multiple profiles are activated like "local,dev", I like to see "user" map as {key1: dev-value, key3: value3} only. but currently it is giving {key1: dev-value, key2:value2, key3:value3}.
is there a way to achieve it?

Create an @ConfigurationProperties class and specify the profile using the @Profile annotation
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Map;

@Component
@Profile("dev")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "user")
public class DevUserProperties {
    private Map<String, String> user;

    public Map<String, String> getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Map<String, String> user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}

Create another one
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Map;

@Component
@Profile("local")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "user")
public class LocalUserProperties {
    private Map<String, String> user;

    public Map<String, String> getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Map<String, String> user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}

In your service, inject the @ConfigurationProperties class according to the active profile
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Map;

@Service
public class UserService {

    private final DevUserProperties devUserProperties;
    private final LocalUserProperties localUserProperties;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(DevUserProperties devUserProperties, LocalUserProperties localUserProperties) {
        this.devUserProperties = devUserProperties;
        this.localUserProperties = localUserProperties;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getUserProperties() {
        if (devUserProperties != null && devUserProperties.getUser() != null) {
            return devUserProperties.getUser();
        } else if (localUserProperties != null && localUserProperties.getUser() != null) {
            return localUserProperties.getUser();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

In this way, you can activate multiple profiles and only get properties from a particular profile.
